# How to add sharepoint hosted app to my office 365 page

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365

I want to add my app to office 365 page.

I have tried the below link:
[How to create an App Part in SharePoint 2013](http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/2013/03/22/how-to-create-an-app-part-in-sharepoint-2013/).

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: I want to know is this a correct link i am referring

Comment: yes..and there are lot many links available. Please try with the steps and let me know if you face any problem. Below is one more link for app part development from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179921(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Comment: @Amit Add your suggestion as answer, and others can be helped from your answer. You can also increase your rep if users upvote your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @BennySkogberg: Thanks for the suggestion. Will keep this in mind while answering questions in future.